# Getter error for array within class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

My constructors within the class need to take an array of Authors instead of a single Author object.

I have written the code for everything else, but the Array doesn't seem to be playing well. I have included only the codes that are related to the array.

```
class myClass {
   ...   
   private Author[] authors;
   ...

   public Book(String name, Author[] authors, double price, int qtyInStock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.price = price;
        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
    }
    public Book(String name, Author[] authors, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.authors= authors;
        this.price = price;

   ...

   public void setAuthors(Author[] authors) {
      this.authors = authors;
   }
   public Author[] getAuthors() {
      for(int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++)
      return authors[i];
   }

   ...

   public void printAuthors() {
        for (Author a : getAuthors())
           System.out.println(a);
    }
    public String toString() {
        if(lenAuthor == 1)
            return String.format(name + " by 1 author");
        else
            return String.format(name + " by " + lenAuthor + "author");
    }
   ...
```

The error I am getting is that it cannot find the Authors symbol. How would I be able to fix my code so that the getAuthors compiles?

Update: I changed the return to

```
return authors[i];
```

and now I'm getting an error incompatible types: Author cannot be converted to Author[]

Comment: Typo: Use `return authors[i];`

Comment: I think you meant to say `authors[i]` instead of `Authors[i]` and your return type might also be invalid. In the future, please refer to this article ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/comment-page-1/). If you have tried debugging and need more help, then make a question about the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Here lies the problem:

```
public Author[] getAuthors() {
  for(int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++)
  return Authors[i];
}
```

You're declaring to return an array of `Author` but return `Authors`, which is a different class name.

I guess you meant to write:

```
public Author[] getAuthors() {
  return authors;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but it would have been better to make a comment and instruct OP on how to debug the program.

Comment: @njzk2 yup, didn't notice, fixed meanwhile

Comment: @AselS and how should he "debug" a program that doesn't compile?

Comment: Just use ide - I bet it's underlined.